# Bind jquery to dynamically generated fields using wildcards in .on selector

Tags: jquery, selector

I have a dynamically generated form that renders fields based on user input. I can not bind events directly to the dynamically generated fields since they don't exist when the DOM is first rendered. However, I can use jquery's ".on' method to bind events through a parent element like document.This works because ".on" accepts a selector to select the child element"

```
.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )
```

In my testing I can pass in a static selector and successfully bind the event like so.

```
$(document).on('click','#id_task_size_edit',function(){
//     $('#id_task_amount').prop('disabled',false).css("background-color","#FFFACD");
```

However the problem is that each field id is also dynamically generated and look like id_task_size_edit_1, id_task_size_edit_2, and id_task_amount_1 etc..

I thought that I could use a wildcard in the selector to catch all events beginning with id_task_size_edit like so

```
$(document).on('click',"'input[id^=id_task_size_edit]'",function(){
```

However that does not work. I've also tried [id*=id_task_size_edit] with and without the "input" any many more combinations of syntax and wildcards, but nothing seems to work. I'm either missing something or wildcards can not be passed to the selector field of jquerys .on function.

How do I accomplish binding events to dynamically generated fields with dynamically generated ids ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just replace `"'input[id^=id_task_size_edit]'"` with `'[id^="id_task_size_edit"]'`. The working example below.

```js
$(document).on('click', '[id^="id_task_size_edit"]', function() {
   $(this).text("It is working!");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="id_task_size_edit_1" type="button">Click Me</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ID`, give them a common `class`, and use that in your JQuery:

```
$(document).on('click','.some_common_class_name',function(){
```